# How to perform a Boolean operation on a Grese pencil object?

Tags: grease-pencil, boolean-modifier

Need to quickly and procedurally hide all Grease pencil lines except the selected area. One of the options is Boolean operation. But it is not clear how to perform such an operation on Grease pencil (so that only the selected area is visible from all angles).

It is important to be precise. That is, I move the selection zone and automatically the Boolean zone moves too, showing me another area of Grease pencil.
[image]
[image]